# Ternary m-to-m-to-m relation in springboot/postgresql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to implement a ternary relation with the entities Customer, CustomerServant and Room. The teranry relation also has the additional attributes StartDate, EndDate and also an Id. Therefore I created this class to get the relation table:

```
@Entity(name = "bookings")
@Table(name = "bookings")
public class Bookings {


@Id
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "bookings_sequence",
        sequenceName = "bookings_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1
)
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy = SEQUENCE,
        generator = "bookings_sequence"
)
@Column(
        name = "bookings_id",
        updatable = false
)
private Long Id;

@Column(
        name = "Travel_Start_Date",
        nullable = false
)
private String travelStartDate ;

@Column(
        name = "Travel_End_Date",
        nullable = false
)
private String travelEndDate;

@ManyToOne (  cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Customer customer = new Customer();

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "room", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Room room;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customerServant", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private CustomerServant customerServant;
```

What I am struggling with is what I should write in the other three classes which are referencing each other.
I do understand that to create a single m-to-m relation with additional relational attributes I can implement a class as I did above and simply write: e.g.

```
 class Bookings {
   int Id;
   Date StartDate;
   Date EndDate;
   
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
   Customer customer;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "Room")
   Room room;
 }
 class Customer {
   //...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
   Set<Bookings> bookings;
 }
 class Room {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
   Set<Bookings> bookings;
```

but what do I do when I want a ternary relation?

Comment: Does this help? https://thorben-janssen.com/ternary-associations/
Based on this article, seems like you've got it right with a `@OneToMany Set<Bookings>` in the other entities.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it using the info provided in the article sent by @warmCabin ([thorben-janssen.com/ternary-associations](https://thorben-janssen.com/ternary-associations/)):

Using an association table class like above with the attributes startDate, endDate, booking_id and the references to the three entities Room, Customer, CustomerServant, provided that theres an according @ManyToOne annotation for the three referencing entities, just like in the question above.

e.g. like above

```
@ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private Customer customer = new Customer();
```

Then I added this to all entities that are connected via the ternary relation:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "<enter varName from ternary relation table>")
   Set<T> var = new HashSet<>();
```

With this line of code, when a relation is stored e.g. a booking like in my case, this relation gets stored in every participating entity and every stored relation gets the Ids of all participating entities.

In my case it would look like this, for the three entities:

```
@Entity(name="Room")
@Table(name="Room")
class Room {

   //attributes...
   
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
   Set<Bookings> bookings = new HashSet<>();
   
   //...
}

@Entity(name="Customer")
@Table(name="Customer")
class Customer {

   //attributes...
   
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
   Set<Bookings> bookings = new HashSet<>();
   
   //...
}

@Entity(name="CustomerServant")
@Table(name="CustomerServant")
class CustomerServant {

   //attributes...
   
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerServant")
   Set<Bookings> bookings = new HashSet<>();
   
   //...
}
```

In the article cited above it is said that its also possible to create such a relation with a HashMap, but because the first appraoch, with an own entity class as a ternary relation, works for me, I didnt check if it would also work in my case. If necessary check the article [thorben-janssen.com/ternary-associations](https://thorben-janssen.com/ternary-associations/).